# Cannot get text centered in a div

Tags: html, css

Could somebody help me with this HTML to make the `<h1>` and `<h2>` texts centrify, because I have lost it a bit on this.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="http://www.pagename.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: black"> 

        <div class="pull-left" style="top: 270 px">
            <img src="pic1.gif" alt="Paradise" width="215px" height="215px"/>  
        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align: center">
            <h1 style="font-size: 7vw; position: relative; top: 2.5vh">PAGENAME.COM</h1> 
            <h2 style="font-size: 2.3vw"SLOGAN FOR THE WEBSITE</h2>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="pull-right" style="margin-left: 1vw";>
    <img src="pic2.gif" alt="Beach" width="215px" height="215px" />  
</div>
```

Comment: Some of your divs are not closed properly. 
https://jsfiddle.net/k99ywpng/.

Comment: ok, got that.Thanks!

Comment: Like @noitse stated, you are missing a closing `</div>`. I fixed the indentation of your code, and it is now quite clear that you are missing a closing tag. This is why it is so important to format your code properly!

Comment: You are also missing a closing `>` by the `<h2` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? 
https://jsfiddle.net/scorpio777/k99ywpng/6/

**CSS**

```
h1 {
  font-size: 7vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5vh
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.3vw
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.pull-left {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.pull-right {
  height: 215px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.center {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="http://www.pagename.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: black">
    <div class="pull-left">
         <img src="pic1.gif" alt="Paradise" width="215px" height="215px"/>  
    </div>

    <div class="center">
          <h1>PAGENAME.COM</h1> 
          <h2>SLOGAN FOR THE WEBSITE</h2>
    </div>
    </a>        
  <div class="pull-right">
      <img src="pic2.gif" alt="Beach" width="215px" height="215px" />  
   </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Now it's better :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS

```
.your-element {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-flow: row wrap !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```